# How to install WIFI driver Ralink corp. RT3090 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe, I am running ubuntu 15.04, 32bit on Hp-Probook-4520s?

Tags: wireless, drivers, 15.04

How to install WIFI driver Ralink corp. RT3090 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe,  I am running ubuntu 15.04, 32bit on Hp-Probook-4520s?
Tried to download from their ralink website as advised in forums but found nothing.

Comment: Try this: download `firmware-ralink` from here: http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/non-free/f/firmware-nonfree/firmware-ralink_0.44_all.deb , install `wireless-tools` if you haven't already (`sudo apt-get install wireless-tools`) and install the driver with `sudo dpkg -i firmware-ralink_0.44_all.deb`.

Comment: thankyou very much for your support, i just find out it was the problem of hard blocked,

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your quick response and support. 
I think driver was already installed by Ubuntu 15.04, 
In terminal I wrote "rfkill list"
found that it was hard off
in terminal wrote "rfkill unblock all"
and here I am using wifi without any problem.