# RT3090 wifi stopped working and reinstalling didn't fix it on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, wireless, realtek-wireless

My wifi connection simply stopped after some error (I don't have the error). The system was unable to find a wireless connection. Wifi is accessible from my TV and smartphone.

The command `iwconfig` shows: `no wireless extensions`.

It also doesn't show a Wireless interface, just the Ethernet interface, even without the cable.

I already have wireless-tools installed and also wpasupplicant. Also, as my Ethernet interface shows that is by Realtek, I tried to install the driver rtl-wifi-new-dkms from the ppa hanipouspilot. The additional drivers doesn't show anything to install. I don't know if my wireless chipset is from Realtek or Intel. My processor is from Intel.

Using a connection via cable, I updated and upgraded everything in the system.

[image: lspci]

[image: lsusb]

[image: lspci -knn | grep Net -A3]

Comment: Ethernet and WiFi are two different and independent devices. The former being Realtek doesn't mean the latter is. Please [edit] your question and add output of  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command so we can know which device you have and if something can be done after the mess you already did.

Comment: I ran the specified command, and it doesn't shows anything. I also ran the command as super, and nothing is showed

Comment: If so it's probably defective. Try removing and re/seating it. If still not detected, time for shopping at your local store or eBay.

Comment: What I should remove and reseat?

Comment: Reseat The WiFi card.

Comment: Include as an edit to your post the output of `lscpi` - does your wireless network card show up in that output?

Comment: Yes. I just attached the print screens, with the result of some commands.

Comment: Please do **not** [crosspost](https://superuser.com/questions/1288693/ubuntu-16-04-3-wifi-dont-work). See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069)

Comment: If I may ask, how 'recent' is this system?  The Ralink 3090 card has had consistently poor driver support for some time now (earliest report of the problem was 2014 with even older kernels and wifi reception problems).  You may be running into this problem because

Comment: My bad. I didn't know about crosspost. I needed the solution as fast as I could get. So posted here, in superuser and also in ubuntu forums. For the future I'll be reading the rules of stack exchange communities, to not do this kind error again.

Comment: My laptop is quite old, more than five years now. But the OS is totally new. I downloaded Ubuntu 16.04.3 yesterday. After the installation I executed: apt-get update, upgrade and dist-upgrade, in order to have the most recent software. So the system is up to date

Comment: Do you have a physical switch on your machine that allows the WiFi to be turned off?  If yes, press it in the other direction, in the other case: the card is probably broken and needs to be replaced / you need to buy a new Linux-compatible WiFi dongle...

Comment: Please copy and paste terminal output rather than posting screen images. It's more efficient. Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/686188/how-to-install-wifi-driver-ralink-corp-rt3090-wireless-802-11n-1t-1r-pcie-i-am

Answer (score 0):

The Ralink RT3090 is [currently supported by the kernel.](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Rt2800pci) via the rt2800pci module that your output indicates is loaded. See the [comment by Fabby.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/999560/rt3090-wifi-stopped-working-and-reinstalling-didnt-fix-it-on-ubuntu-16-04#comment1618857_999560)